# QuickSort for ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, oop, sorting, arraylist, quicksort

I seem to be having some problems witn my quicksort method. I am trying to sort an ArrayList of objects using my quicksort method. I am using the Apache POI library to extract data from an excel file and I am adding this data to my arraylist. I have confirmed that my arraylist is not empty by printing out the arraylist before applying the quicksort method.

My problem seems to be that after passing in my arraylist of objects it gets reset to null and the size of the arraylist becomes 0. I got a java IndexOutOfBounds Exception within my quicksort method while trying get an object from the arraylist. Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Here is my main class :

**EDIT** I solved my problem using the given solution below, but I still don't understand why my quicksort function doesn't work. I would appreciate it if someone could look at the quicksort function and tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks !

```
public class Test {


private static ArrayList<Object> incom = new ArrayList<Object>();


private static int period;
private static String termination = "yes";
private static int pivotVal;

private static ArrayList<String> treatment_name = new ArrayList();
private static ArrayList<Integer> treatment_cstart = new ArrayList();
private static ArrayList<Integer> treatment_cend = new ArrayList();
private static ArrayList<Integer> treatment_cost = new ArrayList();
private static ArrayList<Integer> bridge_part = new ArrayList();
private static ArrayList<Integer> budget = new ArrayList();

private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private static Scanner alt = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");

public static void main(String[] args) 
{   

    processFile();


}

public static void processFile(){
    try {
        POIFSFileSystem fs      =
            new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("Book2.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

        HSSFSheet sheet =wb.getSheet("Table0");
        RowProcessor ip = IncomeProcessor.getInstance();
        Object [] incomes = ip.process(sheet);

        for (int i=0; i<incomes.length; i++)
          incom.add(incomes[i]);

        for (int i=0; i<incom.size(); i++)
        {
            Income income = (Income)incom.get(i);
            System.out.println(income.getBridgeID() + " " + income.getDeckState());
        }


          incom = quicksort(incom);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



public static ArrayList<Object> quicksort(ArrayList<Object> income){

    int pivot = income.size()/2;
    int samePivotVal = 0;
    ArrayList<Object> greater = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ArrayList<Object> lesser = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Income pivotIncome = (Income) income.get(pivot);
    pivotVal = pivotIncome.getDeckState();

    Income in;
    for(int i=0; i<income.size() ;i++){
        in = (Income)income.get(i);
        if(in.getDeckState() > pivotVal)
            greater.add(in);
        else if(in.getDeckState() < pivotVal)
            lesser.add(in);
        else 
            samePivotVal++;
    }


    lesser = quicksort(lesser);
    for(int i=0; i<samePivotVal; i++)
        lesser.add(pivotIncome);

    greater = quicksort(greater);

    ArrayList<Object> sorted = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for(Object result : lesser)
        sorted.add(result);

    for(Object result : greater)
        sorted.add(result);

    return sorted;
    }



}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are implementing your own quicksort?

Comment: I wasn't aware that there is an inbuilt quicksort function. in any case I feel it would be a learning experience to write my own quicksort. Also since its an arraylist of objects i'm not sure how I can use an inbuilt quicksort, because I would like to sort my list based on one of the many integer values in the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be a lot easier (and better) if you use Java's builtin sorting methods.

```
public static void processFile(){ 
    //...

    Collections.sort(incom, new IncomComparator());
    //...
}


class IncomComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        /* compare logic goes here
           return a negative number when o1 < o2
                  a positive number when o1 > o2
                  0 when o1 == o2
        */ 
        return 0;
    }

}
```

or in a more simple way

```
public static void processFile(){ 
    //...

    Collections.sort(incom, new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
           /* compare logic goes here
               return a negative number when o1 < o2
                  a positive number when o1 > o2
                  0 when o1 == o2
           */ 
           return 0;
        }
    });
    //...
}
```

You can see some more examples [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/).

Comment: I tried using that and I got somewhat of an error when trying to call Collections.sort(incom, new IncomComparator());, I got the error saying No enclosing instance of type Test is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Test (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Test).

Comment: If you are trying to define IncomComparator as an inner class see [this](http://tinyurl.com/d5yymof). Or you can use an anonymous comparator (i will add an example to the answer).